# Global Taylor Expansion of a Function on a Manifold with Boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary and let $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Let $r:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ denote the distance to the boundary $d(\cdot, \partial M)$.Let $N\varepsilon = \{ x\in M : r(x)<\varepsilon\}$. It is well known that for small enough $\varepsilon$ we can form boundary normal coordinates.

I was interested in Taylor expanding an integral operator of $f$ near the boundary in terms of $r$. We can write $f$ in boundary geodesic coordinates $(x^1,...x^n)$ on a neighborhood $U$. Where $x^1$ is equal to the distance from the boundary and $(x^2,...,x^n)$ are normal coordinates in a neighborhood $U_\partial$ of $\partial M$. We then have:
$$
\int_{U} f(x^1,...,x^n) \sqrt{|g|}dx^1,...,dx^n = \int_{U} f(0,x^2,...,x^n) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}\Big|_{(0,x^2,...x^n)}x^1 +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial (x^1 )^2}\Big|_{(0,\zeta)}(x^1)^2\sqrt{|g|}dx^1,...,dx^n.
$$

We then can separate out the terms involving $x^1$ to obtain:
$$
\int_{U} f(x^1,...,x^n) \sqrt{|g|}dx^1,...,dx^n = \int_{0}^\varepsilon dx^1 \int_{U_\partial} f(0,x^2,...,x^n) \sqrt{|g|_\partial}dx^2...dx^n + \int_{0}^\varepsilon x^1 dx^1 \int_{U_\partial}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1}\Big|_{(0,x^2,...x^n)}\sqrt{|g|_\partial}dx^2,...,dx^n + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^3)
$$

I am trying to ``patch together'' this local argument into a global result. The first term (up to constant) is really just the integral of $f$ over the boundary. The second term seems like it is $df(\partial_1)$ where $\partial_1$ is the gradient of $r$.

I suspect that I am mistaken. If $\partial M$ is not orientable, then this suggests that grad $r$ is an outward facing globally-defined vector field near the boundary.

I was wondering if there was anyone who could clarify the obstruction here. Is grad $r$ simply not smooth on the boundary? Is that the only problem?

If there is also a good reference on doing analysis on tubular neighborhoods, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm a little confused -- what obstruction are you talking about?  The gradient of $r$ is  as smooth as $M$ -- as least in your collar neighbourhood.   If you were talking about the distance to a submanifold of the interior of $M$, $r$ would not be smooth and the gradient wouldn't exist on the submanifold.

Comment: I think my issue is that the gradient of $r$ is smooth on any normal boundary neighborhood, so shouldn't grad $r$ induce a global outward-facing vector field on $\partial M$? If that were the case, wouldn't it imply that the boundary must be orientable?

Comment: The collar neighbourhood is orientable if and only if the boundary is orientable.  But a non-orientable manifold can easily have a non-orientable boundary, for example, consider the Klein bottle as the boundary of the non-orientable $D^2$-bundle over $S^1$.

Comment: Your analysis is all fine.  I think you are getting anxious because of the well-known observation that boundaries of orientable manifolds are orientable.  And that's due to the fact that a collar neighbourhood of the boundary of any compact manifold $M$ is diffeomorphic to $[0,1) \times \partial M$. i.e. orientability of the boundary is equivalent to orientability of the collar neighbourhood.

Comment: Great! Ok. I guess that since I am not assuming orientability, what happens in the case that the boundary is not orientable? I think I was confused because I thought that global outward-facing vector fields implied orientability of the boundary, but it seems that that is not the case.

Comment: I think your analysis proceeds.  All collar neighbourhoods have outward pointing normal vector fields, that's fine. I think in your case, the vector field is inward pointing, but that's small potatoes.